# PageReference in AuraEnabled class is not working for Lightning Quick Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, pagereference, lightning-quickaction

I have a Quick Action using Lightning Component on Opportunity.
Based on some scenario when a service return Case ID then through Page Reference I would like to return to Case Record Page.

Code :

[image]

**ResCode** has Case Id, but Page reference method is not directing, although URl is getting created in Logs as below:
[image]

Please help

Comment: I am afraid PageReference do only works if those are returned as result of Visualforce Action method execution, and do not work in other apex (i.e. AuraEnabled methods, batch, queueable, triggers and so on)

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be better understood by going to basics - by understanding difference between lightning and visualforce.

- Visualforce to apex is synchronous transaction, thus when pageReference object from apex is returned to a visualforce action, it will perform navigation.
- Lightning to apex is asynchronous transaction, thus all the data transfer takes place through serialization and deserialization.

**Reason for your code not navigating:**

> Apex
>   [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm)
>   object is not serializable and so it cannot be returned in
>   @AuraEnabled methods. If you want to test it, you can try `System.debug(JSON.serialize(Page.MyPageName));` in anonymous apex - this will throw the same error.

**Solution:**

Lightning javascript has its own [pageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) object api which can be used along with [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) for navigation purposes.

You can use below JS for your navigation:

```
component.find("navService").navigate({    
        "type": "standard__recordPage",
        "attributes": {
            "recordId": "001xx000003DGg0AAG",
            "objectApiName": "PersonAccount",
            "actionName": "view"
        }
    })
```

and in aura cmp file:

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

---

As an alternative, you can return url string from apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String redirect(String recordId) {
    // create pagereference 
    return pageRef.getUrl();
}
```

Then in controller.js:

```
component.find("navService").navigate({    
        "type": "standard__webPage",
        "attributes": {
            "url": "/../..." // url returned from apex
        }
    })
```